I'm trying to install dual boot Ubuntu but the installer can't create partitions
I think the Ubuntu installer can't create partitions for Ubuntu. My BIOS mode is Legacy and my partitions are in MBR. First I tried to make my USB drive bootable with Lili USB Creator. It got me to the installation part, but gave me this error.

This is the log of this error:




After this I tried using Rufus for the job, but this time I got stuck in the installer partition table with a Something went wrong error spamming on my desktop.

Have you tried using gparted to create your partitions BEFORE starting the installer?  The installer will let you existing pre-prepared partitions if you're using Manual Partitioning. I can give assurance that the desktop installer will work and create partitions using legacy devices & MBR/DOS partition tables (you don't give clear details of what you're using though), but I find I'm using tools like gparted more often than installers, so find them easier. Did you explore at terminal for clues (pictures of text aren't easy to read)

I see mention of DOS or MBR partitions. How old is system? Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. Systems prior to that really do not work with Ubuntu unless very high end and even then a lightweight flavor would work better. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
